# Loop through the same Case (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'll try to be concise, but basically, I have 2 sets of data that I compare with each other. For that, I have several Cases (depending on which columns I need to compare). The Case's number (xMatch) is an input to the function.

I'm facing the challenge because I need to split my initial data file into several sheets and run each sheet through each Case.
Ideally, I want data from Sheet1 to go through Case1, then data from Sheet2 to go through Case1, and so on. Then do the same for Case 2, then for Case 3. The problem is that the rest of the code is very long and I don't want to copy-paste it inside each Case.

My code is structured like this:

```
Function MatchFinder(ByVal xMatch As Integer) As Boolean

Dim lRow As Long
Dim DataSelect As Range

Split a file into several small files (sheets) based on a condition. Name the sheets

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "blablabla") > 0 Then
       ws.Activate
       ws.Select
       lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
       Set DataSelect = ws.Range("A2:BQ" & lRow)

    End If
Next 'If I put 'Next' here, only the very last sheet will be passed to Case 1, 2, and 3. 
     'If I don't put 'Next' here, the macro will return an error.

Select Case xMatch

Case 1
       compare column A to C
       function_A(DataSelect)

Case 2
       compare column A to D
       function_B(DataSelect)

Case 3
       compare column C to D
       function_C(DataSelect)

End Select
......
Rest of the code
......
```

If I put "For Each ws In Worksheets" and "If InStr(1, ws.Name, "blablabla") > 0 Then" **inside** each Case, then I need to go through the rest of the code (which comes after Cases) and come back to the same Case to pick up a different sheet. But I don't know how to do that. Any ideas or thoughts will be very appreciated. Thank you.

PS. I don't really want to restructure this procedure, I'm hoping I can find a way to make this work!

Comment: 'The problem is that the rest of the code is very long and I don't want to copy-paste it inside each Case.' - this is to be encapsulated in a function/procedure, and only the calling is to be coded to each Case, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How similar are `function_A, function_B, function_C` ? Can you have a function `function_all(DataSelect,xMatch)` ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to build a collection of the ranges you want to process

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To 3
        Call MatchFinder(i)
    Next
End Sub

Function MatchFinder(ByVal xMatch As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngData As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, n As Integer
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Sheet") > 0 Then
           iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
           col.Add ws.Range("A2:BQ" & iLastRow), ws.CodeName
        End If
    Next

    For n = 1 To col.Count
       
        function_All col(n), xMatch
        '.....
        'Rest of the code
        '......

    Next
  
End Function

Sub function_All(rng As Range, xMatch As Integer)

    Select Case xMatch
        Case 1: function_A rng
        Case 2: function_B rng
        Case 3: function_C rng
    End Select

End Sub

Function function_A(rng As Range): Debug.Print "A", rng.Address(1, 1, 1, 1): End Function
Function function_B(rng As Range): Debug.Print "B", rng.Address(1, 1, 1, 1): End Function
Function function_C(rng As Range): Debug.Print "C", rng.Address(1, 1, 1, 1): End Function
```